# Show / hide columns dynamically using JavaScript does not function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My mission is to appear toggle JavaScript in my DataTables but it seems not function not only the button even the functions.

Here is my Code

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 mb-30">
    <table class="data-table stripe hover multiple-select-row nowrap" id="example">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="table-plus datatable-nosort">No</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="table-plus">1</td>
          <td>Michael</td>
          <td>123456789</td>
          <td>michael@gmail.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.onColor = 'success';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.offColor = 'danger';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.size = 'mini';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.state = 'false';
        $.fn.bootstrapSwitch.defaults.inverse = 'true';
        $(".toggle-vis").bootstrapSwitch();
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('.toggle-vis').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am trying to replicate someones code here [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/rh6y7va9/) unfortunately the toggle is not appear.

Comment: Is this a typo in your question? `</tbody>tbody>` or is it actually in your code? Cause that might be the problem.

Comment: I have edit my code and still nothing change with the results.

Comment: what/where is `bootstrapSwitch`. have you defined it somewhere?

Comment: @Scaramouche I don't know where to apply.

Comment: *I don't know where to apply* what?? º_º

Comment: sorry, I am new. I found that code and try to apply in my self project. I am sure there are some code that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 reasons that I see on why it isn't running like the one you're copying.  
**first**: The original author included links that needed for it to works. He added it in the `jsfiddle` left side `Resources url`.  
**second**: The original author included `input` elements in his codes that became the toggle buttons.  
**third**: In the original author `input:checkbox` he included `data-label-text="Position"` which the value should be equal to your column number that starts with `0`. 
  
so if you wish to used the whole functions of the author's code, You need to see every details on how it is going to work.
You can check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/u9h5k048/10/

this is the link you need to add in jsfiddle resources 
`https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js` 
`https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js`
 
`https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css`
 
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css`
 
`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js`
 
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/css/bootstrap2/bootstrap-switch.min.css`
 
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.2/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js`

Comment: Thank You, I just missing 2 links at the bottom of your post which for bootstrap switch.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the toggle-vis element

```
<input 
      type="checkbox" 
      data-column="0" 
      class="toggle-vis" 
      data-label-text="ID" 
      checked/>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      data-column="1" 
      class="toggle-vis" 
      data-label-text="Name" 
      checked>
    <input 
      type="checkbox" 
      data-column="2" 
      class="toggle-vis" 
      data-label-text="Position" 
      checked/>
```

Comment: Already add but nothing changes [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mastersuse/8og5yqxu/9/)

Comment: Issue is you have added script tag inside the fiddle Javascript , so you can see the error in console. You are not required to add <script></script> in the Javascript and fiddle will automatically add those tags.